# magento exclude bundled items from search results

Tags: search, magento, bundle, magento-1.4

Currently, when one searches for an item, the quick search also brings up any bundles that contain items that fit the search criteria. How would I stop this?

A solution that filters out all bundled items from search results all together would be fine too.

> **UPDATE**

I don't want the items to show in either the catalogue or search, but am using them as upsell items. This seems to leave two options:

1. I could amend the search results controller to omit bundled items (the method I was asking about), or
2. I could change the `Upsell.php` script to include "Don't show individually" items.

The second is perhaps easier? Currently the filter applied is:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```

How would I change this so it shows don't show individually items?

Apologies for the incomplete initial question.

> **Second Update:**

Ok, I've added

```
->setVisibility(null)
```

and it already has

```
->addStoreFilter()
```

But there is no change.

Essentially, if I don't have either of:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```

Then I get the following error:

> SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`is_imported`, `e`.`rc_manufacturer`, `e`.`rc_manufacturer_value`, `e`.`rc_vehicle`, `e`.`rc_vehicle_value`, `e`.`rc_assembly_type`, `e`.`rc_assembly_type_value`, `e`.`surface_type`, `e`.`surface_type_value`, `e`.`rc_drive`, `e`.`rc_drive_value`, `e`.`rc_scale`, `e`.`rc_scale_value`, `e`.`rc_motor_type`, `e`.`rc_motor_type_value`, `e`.`rc_engine_start_type`, `e`.`rc_engine_start_type_value`, `e`.`rc_engine_size`, `e`.`rc_engine_size_value`, `e`.`rc_form_factor`, `e`.`rc_form_factor_value`, `e`.`rc_frequency`, `e`.`rc_frequency_value`, `e`.`rc_gear_material`, `e`.`rc_gear_material_value`, `e`.`rc_operation`, `e`.`rc_operation_value`, `e`.`rc_torque_6v`, `e`.`rc_torque_6v_value`, `e`.`rc_speed_6v`, `e`.`rc_speed_6v_value`, `e`.`rc_bearing_type`, `e`.`rc_bearing_type_value`, `e`.`rc_waterproofing`, `e`.`rc_waterproofing_value`, `e`.`rc_battery_application`, `e`.`rc_battery_application_value`, `e`.`rc_input_supply`, `e`.`rc_input_supply_value`, `e`.`rc_power_output_amps`, `e`.`rc_power_output_amps_value`, `e`.`rc_power_output_watts`, `e`.`rc_power_output_watts_value`, `e`.`rc_lead_connector_type`, `e`.`rc_lead_connector_type_value`, `e`.`rc_gear_pitch`, `e`.`rc_gear_pitch_value`, `e`.`rc_nitro_content`, `e`.`rc_nitro_content_value`, `e`.`rc_exhaust_type`, `e`.`rc_exhaust_type_value`, `e`.`rc_engine_starter_type`, `e`.`rc_engine_starter_type_value`, `e`.`rc_head_fitting`, `e`.`rc_head_fitting_value`, `e`.`rc_temperature_rating`, `e`.`rc_temperature_rating_value`, `e`.`rc_oil_type`, `e`.`rc_oil_type_value`, `e`.`rc_container_size`, `e`.`rc_container_size_value`, `e`.`rc_class`, `e`.`rc_class_value`, `e`.`rc_paint_application`, `e`.`rc_paint_application_value`, `e`.`rc_size`, `e`.`rc_size_value`, `e`.`rc_colour`, `e`.`rc_colour_value`, `e`.`rc_pack_contents`, `e`.`rc_pack_contents_value`, `e`.`rc_spare_part_type`, `e`.`rc_spare_part_type_value`, `e`.`rc_oil_weight`, `e`.`rc_oil_weight_value`, `e`.`rc_glue_type`, `e`.`rc_glue_type_value`, `e`.`rc_usage`, `e`.`rc_usage_value`, `e`.`rc_tool_type`, `e`.`rc_tool_type_value`, `e`.`rc_engine_spare_type`, `e`.`rc_engine_spare_type_value`, `e`.`rc_tune_up_type`, `e`.`rc_tune_up_type_value`, `e`.`rc_bearing_pack_type`, `e`.`rc_bearing_pack_type_value`, `e`.`rc_driver_type`, `e`.`rc_driver_type_value`, `e`.`rc_nut_type`, `e`.`rc_nut_type_value`, `e`.`rc_plane_type`, `e`.`rc_plane_type_value`, `e`.`rc_boat_type`, `e`.`rc_boat_type_value`, `e`.`pre_order`, `e`.`pre_order_value`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `links`.`link_id`, `link_attribute_position_int`.`value` AS `position` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 4
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` AS `link_attribute_position_int` ON link_attribute_position_int.link_id = links

I've also tried the following, but get the error:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ended up solving in a completely different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifying the custom module so that I didn't need to worry about this. It may be of some use as it involved using:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('neq' => 'bundle'));
```

Which just excludes all bundle items from a collection.

Answer (score 1):

*Based on your updated question:*
If you are not using Enterprise Edition TargetRule or some other module which automates upsells (i.e. the upsells are defined explicitly by the admin), then likely the simplest approach is that which you've specified - rewrite the Upsell block to not add the visibility filter. As a guess, to be optimal you may want to call `setVisibility(null)` and `addStoreFilter()` on the collection to trigger normal limiting behavior.

**EDIT: Original answer below**

- Admin > Catalog > Manage Products grid
- Choose "Bundle Product" from the filters area at the top, click "Search"
- Click "Select All"
- Select "Update Attributes" from the mass action block's "Action" dropdown, click "Submit"
- Change the "Visibility" attribute to "Catalog"

Comment: I apologise, I didn't give more detail above: I'll update the question now.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Still no luck unfortunately. I've added details to the question.

Comment: Ben, I ended up finding a solution that works for my purposes, but instead of letting the bounty go to waste, and given you've clearly given a lot of helpful answers in the [magento] space, I'm awarding it to you. Thanks for your answer.